# Calling Application_Start in Owin Self-Hosting application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

I have an ASP WebAPI application that works great.
Without changing anything massive within the application, I'm trying to create a new console project with self-hosting components to host the application (mainly for running it fast when debugging other components of my solution without opening and compiling from Visual Studio).

I saw plenty of solutions for using *Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SelfHost* package, 
For example: [Working With OWIN Hosting and Self Hosting in ASP.Net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/working-with-owin-hosting-and-self-hosting-in-Asp-Net/).

All the solutions I saw, use the following structure:

```
       string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/"; 

        // Start OWIN host 
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress)) 
        { 
            // Create HttpCient and make a request to api/values 
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 

            var response = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/values").Result; 

            Console.WriteLine(response); 
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); 
        } 

        Console.ReadLine();
```

This is a bit problematic for me, since  `using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress))` is calling the **Configuration** method in **Startup** class.

```
  public class Startup 
{ 
    // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
    // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) 
    { ... }
}
```

My solution has plenty of code inside the **Application_Start()** (inside the Global.aspx.cs file) that I'm trying to reach when starting the console self-host application. So far without any success.

Is this a lost battle and I should move as much as I can from Application_Start method to Configuration method? Or is there any way I call call the Application_Start somehow, prior to running the Configuration method?

I tried creating an instance of the ASP application and call the Application_Start, but that didn't work.

Thanks!
Guy

Comment: If you self host the web application on OWIN without System.Web, then why not hook to OWIN events instead of the legacy events?

Comment: Global.aspx.cs and Application_Start() are System.Web constructs that are unavailable in self-host. Move that code into Startup.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering that this is what I had to do.